# How to insert a row and format a row of Excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5, com-interop

I created an excel file using `Microsoft.Office.interop`. Now i want to add headings for all columns in that excel file. Also want to bold, color the heading row.

I have something like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; //initialize&create,open app,wb,... 
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++) {
    WorkSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 1] = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 1]; 
    xlWorkSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 2] = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 2]; rCnt2++; 
}
```

For formatting, i often use

```
range1=xlworksheet.get_Range("A1","A4"); 
range1.Font.Bold;
```

Could u provide c# code for this using interop?

Comment: No one will provide you code if you don't try something yourself first.

Comment: using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
//initialize&create,open app,wb,...
 for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
  {WorkSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 1] = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 1];
                    xlWorkSheet2.Cells[rCnt2, 2] = xlWorkSheet.Cells[rCnt, 2];
                    rCnt2++;
                }
            }
       
For ex, in my above code i write some values in col1 and col2 of wb2.
Now i want to insert a row and put heading for my xls file.
How to insert a row at the top of my testfile2.xls??
Is there any built in function like insertrow?

Comment: for formatting i use range1=xlworksheet.get_Range("A1","A4"); range1.Font.Bold;

Comment: It'd be a lot easier on the eyes if you could please update your original post and use the `code tag` in the editor, rather than posting the code in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

In order to **set the color of a range**, you have to alter the `Interior.Color` attribute.

```
Application.Range[Application.Cells[startRow, startCol], Application.Cells[endRow, endCol]].Interior.Color = YourColorValue
```

I believe the number `15395562` is light gray, so you could give that a shot by replacing `YourColorValue` with that number to ensure it's working.

To **Insert a row** at the very top of your workbook, you must first `Select` the entire first row, then perform an `Insert` operation with the parameter that explicitly states to shift all other rows downward, which would look something like this:

```
((Range)((Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).Rows[1]).Select();
((Range)App.Selection).Insert(Shift: XlDirection.xlDown);
```

Please note that this code is untested and is meant to give you an idea of what needs to be done and how you might go about doing it. Please try it out, if you come across issues *then* we can further assist you. The point is for you to learn along the way.